# Arduino c++ callback in class methods

Tags: c++, class, arduino, callback, this

I'm new to Arduino and C++ and I have a question about arduino (c++), class and "this" in class methods:

I create classname.cpp and classname.h
In classname.cpp I try get "this" (ClassName instance) somehow (example below):

```
ClassName::ClassName(){}

...
void SomeCallback(char* name, uint8_t age){
    // how to get "this" object (ClassName)?
}
...
void ClassName::Init(){
    this->someobj->setCallback(someCallback); // callback signature <void(char*, uint8_t)>
}
```

In this solution I don't have the compiler error, but I can't get "that" in some callbacks

The question is:
How do I modify the Init method or someCallback function to get "this" in SomeCallback?

I try put someCallback in to class like this:

ClassName::SomeCallback(char* name, uint8_t age)

Comment: Do you have control over the signature of the callback that `setCallback` accepts? Is `setCallback` something you wrote, or part of a third-party library?

Comment: Your callback function appears to be limited to calling C code, and it cannot be changed to use C++ class methods, without some ugly, error-prone hacks that involve `static`ally scoped pointers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - unfortunately, this is part of another library with a setCallback method

Comment: Most of the time a callback registration function takes a "user pointer" that you can use to identify which object should receive the callback. If this isn't available, you'll have to invent something messy.

Comment: Could you show the actual signature of `setCallback`; or better still, link to its documentation? Sometimes, the library provides a way to stash additional information that is passed to the callback.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - this is the API of library https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api

Comment: That's an unfortunate design. You'll probably have to maintain some kind of a global map from topic to `ClassName` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
void SomeCallback(char* name, uint8_t age){
    // how to get "this" object (ClassName)?
}
```

Since this function is not a member of the class, there is no `this` for it to refer to.  If you had three instances of ClassName in your code, then which `this` should it refer to?

Class members use this to refer to whichever class instance they are a part of.  When you create instances and use them:

```
ClassName instance1
ClassName instance2

void setup() {

   instance1.Init();
   instance2.Init();
}
```

for that first call to `Init`, `this` points to instance1.  For the second call to `Init` `this` points to instance 2.

But in your callback method it is not a member of a class.  So it doesn't get called with a class instance, so it doesn't have a `this`.

How you solve this problem depends on what you want the program to do.  If you only will have one instance of the class, then make it a singleton.  OR don't even make it a class.  If you will have multiple instances then one option is to have a static list of pointers to instances and let the instances "register" themselves for callbacks by adding themselves to that list.